# Where can I read Cauchy's terrible poems?

Tags: biographical-details, reference-request, cauchy

I hope that the slightly abrasive title is forgivable, as the judgement on this poetry is not mine, but Hans Freudenthal's. Here is the background: in the Dictionary of Scientific Biography, [there is an entry on Augustin-Louis Cauchy](https://www.encyclopedia.com/people/science-and-technology/mathematics-biographies/augustin-louis-cauchy) written by Freudenthal.  It is an excellent biography, but there is one line in there which surprised me:

> [Cauchy] also produced French and Latin poetry, which, however, is better forgotten.

Freudenthal was [apparently](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Freudenthal/) quite interested in and well-read on the subject of poetry, so this judgement might well be sound -- but I'd like to find out for myself! I am unable to find any trace of this harshly sentenced poetry of Cauchy's online, so my question is precisely as stated in the title!

Comment: Augustin Cauchy, « Épître d’un mathématicien à un poète, ou La leçon d’astronomie », Bulletin de l’Institut catholique, n° 1, 13 janvier 1842, p. 13-20 ; (cf. Belhoste B , *AL Cauchy, a biography*, Springer 1991)

Comment: The following publication only reproduces the introduction, not the actual poem: Nicolas Wanlin, "Le poème didactique : un genre réactionnaire ?". *La Révolution française. Cahiers de l’Institut d’histoire de la Révolution française* 7 (2014), ([online](https://journals.openedition.org/lrf/1198))